# Optimization : Check if someone else is connected

Tags: python, linux

I would like to know if someone is logged on a computer. To do that, I wrote this little script, but i would like to know if there's a better way to do that.

```
import os

def get_sessions():
    process = os.popen('who | grep -v "\(unknown\)"')
    result  = process.read()
    process.close()

    fields = ["login", "tty", "date", "time", "hostname"]
    return map(lambda x: dict(zip(fields, x.split())), result.splitlines())


def is_someone_else_logged():
    username = os.getlogin()
    return filter(lambda x: x["login"] != username, get_sessions()) != []
```

Also, can you please notice me every non-pythonics things i did here ?

Comment: You should try posting this at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Because it's a short script and just a short optimization, i though it would be okay to post it here. Should i really go on CodeReview ?

Comment: Also, i should edit my question to "How to do a who in Python" because i didn't found another topic about that on SO

Comment: You should really not be using os,popen. Use the subprocess module

Comment: @FunkySayu It's fine here, don't worry :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the logged in users use `subprocess.check_output` with the `users` command to just get the logged in users:

```
from subprocess import check_output
from os import getlogin

c = check_output("users")
users = set(c.split())

print(all(user in {getlogin(),'(unknown)' } for user in users))
```

Comment: On my system, this doesn't work exactly like that. First `users` return all users logged in one line (solved with `c.split()`) and the condition is the following : `return not any(not user in [getlogin(), '(unknown)'] for user in users)`. `(unknown)` occures when the login interface of Gnome is waiting for an user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use psutil's get_users(), check https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil